# How to generate on the fly Java source code to build with Gradle in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

As part of an Android app that uses the NDK, I need to export some constants from the C/C++ world into Java. For obvious reasons, I'd rather have this automated. I'm using Android Studio with the NDK support.

How can I generate some `.java` file on the fly from a shell script that would be ran by Gradle whenever the app builds? Ideally this `.java` file would go in an build intermediaries directory somewhere and wouldn't have to be in the app source directory.

As an example, the shell script would generate this Java source:

```
public enum Type {
  FOO,
  BAR
}
```

from this C++ source:

```
enum class Type {
  FOO,
  BAR
}
```

For reference here's a simplified version of the Gradle file I'm starting from in Android Studio:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.model.application'

model {

    compileOptions.with {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }

    android {
        compileSdkVersion = 23
        buildToolsVersion = "23.0.2"

        defaultConfig.with {
            applicationId = "..."
            minSdkVersion.apiLevel = 18
            targetSdkVersion.apiLevel = 23
        }

        defaultConfig.multiDexEnabled = true
    }

    android.ndk {
        platformVersion = "18"
        moduleName = "jni"
        ...
    }

    android.buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles.add(file('proguard-rules.txt'))
            ndk.with {
                CFlags.add("-Werror")
                cppFlags.add("-Werror")
            }
        }
    }

    android.productFlavors {
        create("arm7") {
            ndk.abiFilters.add("armeabi-v7a")
        }
    }

}

repositories {
    ...
}

dependencies {
    ...
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just write the generated file to the `$buildDir/generatedJava` then add that directory as a source folder.  Then make the task `javaCompile` depend on your task that generates the source.  Something like this could be used inside a `build.gradle`

```
def outputJavaFile = new File("$buildDir.absolutePath/generatedJava", 'MyEnum.java')
task generateSources(type: Exec) {
    def source = $/
package com.example;
public enum Something {
   One,
   Two
}
/$

    if (!outputJavaFile.parentFile.exists()) {
        outputJavaFile.parentFile.mkdirs()
    }
    outputJavaFile.withWriter {
        it << source
    }
}

compileJava.dependsOn outputJavaFile

sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDirs 'src/main/java', outputJavaFile.absolutePath
        }
    }
}

// if the goal is to generate the source from a script then just call the script
// inside the Exec closure
task shellScriptToGenerateSources(type: Exec) {
    commandLine 'myShellScript.sh'
}
// then make compileJava depend on the task that runs the script
compileJava.dependsOn shellScriptToGenerateSources
```

Edit: To apply the same logic to your updated `build.gradle` file might look something like this

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.model.application'

// define an output folder for our generated .java files
def GENERATED_JAVA_OUTPUT = "$buildDir/generatedJava"
// if the goal is to generate the source from a script then just call the script
// inside the Exec closure
task shellScriptToGenerateSources(type: Exec) {
    commandLine 'myShellScript.sh'
}
// then make compileJava depend on the task that runs the script
compileJava.dependsOn shellScriptToGenerateSources

model {

    compileOptions.with {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }

    android {
        compileSdkVersion = 23
        buildToolsVersion = "23.0.2"

        defaultConfig.with {
            applicationId = "..."
            minSdkVersion.apiLevel = 18
            targetSdkVersion.apiLevel = 23
        }

        defaultConfig.multiDexEnabled = true
    }

    android.ndk {
        platformVersion = "18"
        moduleName = "jni"
        ...
    }

    android.buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles.add(file('proguard-rules.txt'))
            ndk.with {
                CFlags.add("-Werror")
                cppFlags.add("-Werror")
            }
        }
    }

    android.productFlavors {
        create("arm7") {
            ndk.abiFilters.add("armeabi-v7a")
        }
    }

    // let android know that our java sources shoudl also consider the generated java for the compiler
    android.sourceSet {
        main {
            java {
                srcDir(GENERATED_JAVA_OUTPUT)
            }
        }
    }
}

repositories {
    ...
}

dependencies {
    ...
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: Thanks for this. How would run a shell script through instead of defining the java source inline?

Comment: See edit.  I added an example of how to run a script inside a `type: Exec` closure.  You just have to make the script point to the dir defined in `sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs`.  The task `shellScriptToGenerateSources` will fail if your script exits with a non zero value.

Comment: Thanks again. I just have a hard time reconciling your Gradle sample with the format used by Android Studio (see my updated question) - how do you merge your changes into the Android Studio Gradle file?

Comment: Updated answer to address your specific build.gradle setup

Comment: Is the generateSources task run every time gradle is invoked? Is the file made each time the build runs, even if no other file changes?